# Python CSV: Loop stops after reaching empty row

Tags: python

I want to read a CSV file generated by my other script and I need to check 2 columns at same time. The problem is that my loop its stopping because there are empty values for some lines and It cant reach the following value. For example:

1. HASH 1111
2. HASH 2222
3. HASH 3333
4. HASH 4444
5. HASH 5555
6. HASH
7. HASH
8. HASH 6666

I cant read further point 5, because 6 and 7 has empty values and I need to read also the 8. Here is my code.

```
import csv

with open('vts.csv') as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile, delimiter=';')
    next(csvReader)  

    VTs = []

    for row in csvReader:
        VT = row       
        VTs.append(VT)

    for row in VTs:
        print(row[0],row[4])
```

Is there any way to continue the listing without manually sorting the Excel?

Comment: `delimiter=';'` contradicts with presented input content

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I don't think so, code its reading 205 rows without any problems, but at the 206 is an empty value in the CSV and the loop stops. Also my columns are delimited by semicolon.

Comment: "your columns" ? You did not post any content delimited with semicolons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a csv file is **not** an Excel file. The former is a text delimited file, the latter is a binary one.

Next, your problem is not at reading time: the csv module can easily accept files with variable number of fields across its rows, including empty lines *that will just give empty lists for `row`*.

So the fix is just:

```
...
for row in VTs:
    if len(row) > 4:
        print(row[0],row[4])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly. Also I know that its not an Excel file, but I had to do that workaround in order to get everything working.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code except for the `print(row[0],row[4])` for the given data while there no so many columns. I tested your code as follows:

.py

```
import csv

with open('vts.csv') as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile, delimiter=';')
    next(csvReader)

    VTs = []

    for row in csvReader:
        VT = row
        VTs.append(VT)

    for row in VTs:
        print(row[0], row[1])
```

vts.csv

```
HASH;1111
HASH;2222
HASH;3333
HASH;4444
HASH;5555
HASH;
HASH;
HASH;6666
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is as the sample, you don't really need `delimiter=';'` since it's a comma-separated value (hence `csv`), not semicolon `;`.

Anyway, you can just ignore if the intended column not exists. Assuming your input is in proper csv format as below.

```
col1,col2
hash1,1111
hash2,2222
...
```

You can use `csv.reader` as what you did.

```
import csv

with open('vts.csv') as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile, delimiter=';')
    next(csvReader)  

    # csv.reader returns generator object, which you can convert it to list as below
    VTs = list(csvReader) 

    for row in VTs:
        if len(row) == 2:
            print(row[0],row[1])
```

If your goal is only for inspecting the data, you can conveniently use [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("vts.csv")
print(df.dropna()) # This will print all rows without any missing data
```